# can't get the right shape of TensorFlow custom layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to train a model in TensorFlow with custom layers.
I am having a problem with the last layer, I am trying to build a layer that gets a batch of images [None,100,100,1] and returns the sum of 10 different square zones, so the output should be the shape of [None,10].

I've tried some different approaches with no success.
I've tried:

```
        output = tf.concat([tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[34:42, 28:40,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[34:42, 44:56,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[34:42, 60:72,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[46:54, 20:32,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[46:54, 36:48,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[46:54, 52:64,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[46:54, 68:80,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[58:66, 28:40,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[58:66, 44:56,0]), [1,]),
                            tf.reshape(tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[58:66, 60:72,0]), [1,])], axis= 0)
```

and similar sum functions, but couldn't get the shapes first dimension to 'None'.

I have tried 'cheating' by reshaping the input into the right shape then multiplying by 0 and adding a tensor with the size [10]. this got the right shape, but the model didn't train.

is there a proper way of doing this? I'm stuck on this issue for weeks with no luck.

the model trains fine if I put a different layer that doesn't do what I want, but it has the right output shape:

```
class output_layer(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, shape_input):
        self.shape_input = shape_input
        super(output_layer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = tf.math.multiply(inputs,tf.math.conj(inputs))
        temp = tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs, axis=2)
        temp = tf.reshape(temp, [-1,10,10])
        temp = tf.math.reduce_sum(temp, axis=2)        
        output = tf.cast(temp, tf.float32)
        output = tf.keras.activations.softmax(output, axis=-1)
        return output
```

If anyone can help me with this i will really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code and come up with the following:

```
output = tf.concat(
                  [tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 34:42, 28:40,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 34:42, 44:56,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 34:42, 60:72,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 20:32,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 36:48,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 52:64,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 68:80,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 58:66, 28:40,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 58:66, 44:56,:], axis=[1,2]),
                   tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 58:66, 60:72,:], axis=[1,2])], axis=-1)
```

Notice I changed `inputs[34:42, 28:40, 0]` to `inputs[:, 34:42, 28:40,:]`. You can use `:` for dimensions you want to keep the same. I also specified which axis should be reduced, and, therefore, only dimensions without the specification to be reduced will remain—in this case, it is the first and last dimension. In your case, the `tf.math.reduce_sum` will produce shape [None, 1].
Along with that, I changed the axis of `tf.concat` to -1, which is the last layer, so it produces shape [None, 10].

For completeness, you can create your own layer. To do so, you have to inherit from tf.keras.layers.Layer.

Then, you can use it as any other layer.

```
class ReduceZones(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ReduceZones, self).__init__()
      
    def build(self, input_shapes):
        return
      
    def call(self, inputs):
        output = tf.concat(
                [tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 34:42, 28:40,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 34:42, 44:56,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 34:42, 60:72,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 20:32,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 36:48,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 52:64,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 46:54, 68:80,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 58:66, 28:40,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 58:66, 44:56,:], axis=[1,2]),
                 tf.math.reduce_sum(inputs[:, 58:66, 60:72,:], axis=[1,2])], axis=-1)
        return output
```